# 32 Bit Access and 32 Bit Java

Tags: java, netbeans, 32bit-64bit

I have 32 bit Java Installed with 32 Bit Netbeans (64 Bit Laptop) and have Office Access 2007 32 Bit.

I am getting a problem when I am trying to connect a database to my java project.

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
java.lang.NullPointerException

```
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String SourceURL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=" 
                + new File("Argos.accdb").getAbsolutePath() + ";";
        //MAY CHANGE THE ADMIN PART (Remove Admin)

        Argos = DriverManager.getConnection(SourceURL, "admin","");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.stoneedge.com/help/OM_DOC/tips_tricks/Creating_ODBC_Connection_in_Windows.html

- Click on the Start Menu.
- Select Control Panel.
- Select Administrative Tools and double click the Data Sources (ODBC) icon.
- Click on the System DSN tab.
- Click the Add button.
- Select Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb) from the drivers list and click the Finish button.
- Provide the mdb file... to database and provide name "Importer"

Comment: When i Click on Add the options are only Sql Server and Sql Server Native Client 10.0